# Problem in json parsing iphone sdk?

Tags: json, ios4

I have following json file.

```
{
    "id": "100001740605903",
    "name": "Mike Watshan",
    "first_name": "Mike",
    "last_name": "Watshan",
    "education": [
        {
            "school": {
                "id": "21657666681",
                "name": "University of Georgia"
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "133832199985127",
                "name": "2004"
            },
            "type": "College"
        },
        {
            "school": {
                "id": "106425642726879",
                "name": "Valley High School"
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "136656086362466",
                "name": "2002"
            },
            "type": "High School"
        }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "timezone": 5.5,
    "locale": "en_US"
}
```

And use following code to parse json.

```
//jsonString is valid NSString object who contains valid json string.
//arrPro is NSArray object.

SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
self.arrPro = [json objectWithString:jsonString error:&error];
NSLog(@"stringObject %@",[[self.arrPro objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

But get the errer.Please help me....

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b51520'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting Object Of NSDictionary instead of NSArray...

use this instead

```
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSdictionary *dict  = [json objectWithString:jsonString error:&error];
```

Print this dictionary
inside dict you will find array 
Simple json returns array where complicated json like this returns dictionary

Thanks